# Description of pull-back of coherent sheaves under a smooth morphism of Artin stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, coherent-sheaves

I am new to these formalisms, so pardon me if the question is basic. Let $\mathscr{X}$ be an Artin stack (you can take it to be Deligne-Mumford stack if it helps). By a coherent sheaf on $\mathscr{X}$ we mean the data of a coherent sheaf coherent sheaf on the Lisse-'etale site on $\mathscr{X}$, i.e. a coherent $\mathcal{O}_U$-module $\mathcal{F}_u$ for each smooth atlas $u:U\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ satisfying certain compatibility conditions.

Let $f: \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathscr{Y}$ be a smooth morphism between two Artin stacks (again, you can assume they are DM-stacks). Since $f$ is smooth, we get an induced map from the Lisse-'etale site of $\mathscr{X}$ to the Lisse-'etale site of $\mathscr{Y}$.

My question is the following: Can we describe the pull-back $f^*\mathcal{F}$ of a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathscr{X}$ simply by associating to each smooth atlas $v :V\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ the $\mathcal{O}_V$-module $\mathcal{F}_{f\circ v}$? Martin Olsson in his book "Algebraic spaces and stacks" gives a rather complicated description of the pull-back under an arbitrary morphism of stacks, giving the reason that an arbitrary morphism of stacks does not give a morphism of Lisse-'etale topoi, but it seems to me that in the case for smooth morphisms it should be equivalent to the one that I described.

Is my idea correct? Can someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. For non-smooth morphisms you can give a similar description using the fact that specifying a compatible collection of quasi-coherent sheaves on schemes $U$ for smooth $U \to \mathscr{X}$ is equivalent to specifying it on all schemes $U$ over $\mathscr{X}$.

Comment: @crystalline Thank you for the comment. Do you know of any reference? I think I have an idea how to prove it quoting some paper of M.Olsson, but it seems like it should be written somewhere.

Comment: I'm a little confused but what does $f \circ v$ mean? How do you compose these two maps?

Comment: @DavidBenjaminLim Oops, thank you for pointing out the typo. The target for $v$ should have been $\mathscr{X}$. I have corrected it now.